Congruence relation on the monoid $(\mathbb N, +)$
Problem: Consider the monoid $(\mathbb N, +)$. Let $m, n\in \mathbb N$ and $m\geq 1$. Let $R_{m,n}$ be the equivalence relation $$xR_{m,n}y \Leftrightarrow x=y \quad \text{or} \quad (x\geq n \text{ and } y\geq n \text{ and } m\mid x-y)$$ in the set $\mathbb N$. We know that the relation is compatible with the addition in the monoid; alternatively, we know it is a congruence relation. Disregarding the trivial relations, that is $x\sim y$ for all $x, y\in \mathbb N$ and $x\sim y \iff x=y$, show that every (equivalence) relation in $\mathbb N$, that is compatible with the addition, is necessarily of the form $R_{m, n}$.
So far: Nothing really. Since the relation must be reflexive, the first condition is obviously satisfied. However, it is not clear why the relation must become ''$\mathbb Z_m$'' after some treshold $m\geq 2$. I guess we can disregard the case $m=1$, since this would yield one of the trivial relations?

Well, the case $m=1$ is live since $n$ need not be $1$.  That's the case for which all numbers above some threshold are equivalent (and everything is equivalent to itself)

The question is equivalent to the classification of the cyclic monoids. This has been explained here on the site for sure. Maybe someone else finds a corresponding duplicate.
